# Как реализовать обработку длительного нажатие кнопки в Renpy на ПК?

Tags: python, разработка-игр, renpy

Для кнопок есть несколько возможных действий - действие при нажатии (action), действие при наведении (hovered), действие при отведении курсора (unhovered) и тд. Я же хочу реализовать мини-игру, для которой нужно будет не однократно кликать на кнопку, а зажимать ее. Такой сценарий легко написать для телефонов и планшетов используя hovered и unhovered, но с ПК я уже долго бодаюсь и ничего придумать не могу.

Comment: модуль mouse вам не поможет ? https://github.com/boppreh/mouse#mouse.is_pressed

Comment: Спасибо огромное, теперь одна проблема осталась позади :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Renpy действительно нет отслеживания нажатия и отжатия кнопки, но можно воспользоваться сторонними библиотеками.